# Unterminated string at character while parsing the JSON

Tags: java, jquery, json

I have a JSON which the jsonlint shows as a valid JSON but when I call

```
JSONObject rootObj=new JSONObject(orderJsonStr);
```

am getting `org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 13755`, the place where it is break has    `"value": "12312&"`, it is breaking in place of `'&'`. Do we need to escape & or can we use a `urlEncoder` to encode the JSON?

Comment: are you sure it because of `&` in most of the cases when this exception is thrown is due to not escaped double quotes like `"key":"value"a""`

Comment: Yes am sure about &. the exception shows the position of the character where it is breaking.. that is actually the position of &

Comment: then try to escape it `\&` to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

For special characters in your json meesage like \ , @ , & , # etc.. first convert them into their respective HEX value and then send your message.

Comment: am doing it by saying %26 for & while sending it with ajax request. When I read the parameter in my servlet, it reads that as & but not %26